# How to use an alpha map in Blender Render?

Tags: texturing

[image]

Whenever I download Nintendo models I come across this texture with the black. I can't transparent it, but how do I use this for stuff in Blender Render mode? If it's possible can you tell me what I do with these kind of textures?

Comment: This is an alpha map. White represents visible area and black represents transparent area. Since the Triforce has X-axis symmetry the artist only needed to create half of the shape as a graphic, to improve performance. The other half is probably made from a flipped UV map. Please explain what you mean by "how do I use it for stuff". What do you want to do with it? Why do you think you are supposed to do something with it? Your question should be made more clear. If your question is "how to use an alpha map in Blender Render", there is probably an answer on this site already, so search first.

Comment: I tried using transparency against it, but it won't make the black area disappear, so it might be a shadow or something. I know it's a mirror UV, but with alpha channels in Blender Render it won't make it transparent.

Comment: The texture doesn't have an alpha channel. It *is* the alpha channel. So you need to tell Blender to use the grayscale data to control alpha instead of color. When you say you "tried using transparency", what settings did you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## How to use an alpha map in the Blender Internal Render Engine

[image: Using a black and white alpha map to control transparency in the Blender Internal Render Engine]

### In the Material context:

Enable "Transparency" and turn the Alpha slider down to 0. This means at its most transparent it will have zero visibility.

### In the Texture context:

Set the Influence to be Alpha instead of Color. You'll probably want this slider to be at 1, since this controls the total transparency of the texture. If you lower it, even the opaque parts will become somewhat transparent.

[image]

Comment: Oh it was because the RGB to Intensity was disabled.

Comment: I'm glad you got it sorted. :-)